# How to make a histogram of one variable with respect to another

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I was given the following task: "Make a histogram plot with 30 bins for the selected daily mean temperatures using all data of the years 1981-2010. Then repeat this and add a histogram into the same plot for the daily mean temperatures of the years 1961-1990."

I have my avgt and yearly data imported. I know how to plot avgt.

```
plt.hist(avgt, bins=30, edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('Average T')
plt.ylabel('Times Occured')
```

But how do I get it to just be within the years of 1981-2010. They are part of the same dataset I believe.

Comment: Post all of your code and the first 10 lines of your dataset (preferably in csv format) so we can use it to help you.

Comment: What does your data look like? And how are you creating the variable `avgt`?

Comment: You will have to create a subset of `avgt`, of course.  We can't advise you how to do that without knowing how `avgt` was created.